# How to remove row from a JavaScript dynamic table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

My problem is that I am trying to make every line added by the user of the program be removed, but only line by line, as I will show below. Currently my program is removing all the rows from the table and that is not the objective, yes, that added many - as many as the user wants -, that he has the possibility of removing a row, if he wants.

```js
var tituloPag = document.getElementById("titulo");



tituloPag.addEventListener("click", function() {
  tituloPag.textContent = "Bem vindo a sua agenda";
});


var botaoAdd = document.getElementById("adicionar-contato");

botaoAdd.addEventListener("click", addContato);

function addContato(event) {
  event.preventDefault();




  var contatoTr = document.createElement("tr");

  var formContato = document.getElementById("formulario");


  var nomeTd = document.createElement("td");
  var emailTd = document.createElement("td");
  var celularTd = document.createElement("td");
  var instaTd = document.createElement("td");
  var faceTd = document.createElement("td");
  var excluirTd = document.createElement("td");


  nomeTd.textContent = formContato.nome.value;

  emailTd.textContent = formContato.email.value;
  celularTd.textContent = formContato.cel.value;
  instaTd.textContent = formContato.insta.value;
  faceTd.textContent = formContato.face.value;
  excluirTd.innerHTML = "<button class='btn btn-danger excluir'><i class='fa fa-trash-o' >Excluir</i></button>";

  contatoTr.appendChild(nomeTd);
  contatoTr.appendChild(emailTd);
  contatoTr.appendChild(celularTd);
  contatoTr.appendChild(instaTd);
  contatoTr.appendChild(faceTd);
  contatoTr.appendChild(excluirTd);



  var agendaTabela = document.getElementById("corpoAgenda");
  agendaTabela.appendChild(contatoTr);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<div class="p-5 text-black text-center bg-roxo">
  <h1 id="titulo">João Augusto</h1>
</div>

<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="container">

    <h5>Agenda</h5>
    <form id="formulario">
      <div class="row py-2">
        <div class="col-1">
          <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5 ">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escrava o primeiro nome" name="nome">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row py-2">
        <div class="col-1">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="email" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
          <label for="cel">Celular:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="(XX)XXXX-XXXX" name="cel">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row py-2">
        <div class="col-1">
          <label for="insta">Instagram:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Instagram" name="insta">
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
          <label for="face">Facebook:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Facebook" name="face">
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="salvarexcluir">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="adicionar-contato">Salvar</button>


        <button class='btn btn-danger exluir'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'>Excluir</i></button>

      </div>



    </form>

  </div>


  <div class="container mt-3">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="myTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Celular</th>
          <th>Instagram</th>
          <th>Facebook</th>
          <th>Excluir</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody id="corpoAgenda">

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="mt-5 p-4 bg-dark text-white text-center">

</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "but only line by line", but more importantly you don't seem to have included the relevant code; there's a commented-out call to `tabela.deleteRow` but the function itself isn't visible. All we have is the code that adds to the table.  Can you please more clearly explain what you're trying to do (preferably not in ALL CAPS) and include a [mcve] demonstrating what's not working as expected?

Comment: my problem is that the program is removing all contacts added in the phonebook - because the program is a phonebook. And this happens when I click the "delete" button. The objective is that the user can add all the contacts he wants, but only have the possibility to remove one at a time.

Comment: I understand what you're after now, thanks (andd I missed that you were trying to use the native DOM deleteRow method, thought you had a custom function by that name.)  For future reference, try removing irrelevant code from your question, and *don't* comment out the parts that aren't working; that makes it more difficult for us to see what's significant andd to determine what's going wrong.

Comment: I made the edits you asked for. Is it understandable now?

Comment: As already stated in the comments, "PLEASE STOP YELLING". Questions/titles in all caps can be interpreted as you yelling at us, and people aren't keen to help people who are yelling at them. Please consider [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75177528/edit) and removing the "ALL CAPS" sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to add your "delete" action globally for the table, assign the click event separately to each individual row's delete button, so it can get a reference to the row you actually want to delete.

The significant change here was to add these lines to your row creation function:

```
  // attach the "delete" action to this button for this row
  excluirTd.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", () => {
    deletar(contatoTr)
  })
```

Previously your code attempted to pass a reference to the button to your `deletar` function, and then traverse to its parentNode to find the row and its rowIndex.  This didn't work because the button's parent node was actually the `<td>`, not the `<tr>` you wanted.  You could fix that by using `parentNode.parentNode`, but that would be pretty fragile; instead I changed it to simply pass the row itself, since you conveniently already ha a reference to it in `contatoTr`.

Demonstration below (with some extraneous code and layout removed):

```js
function deletar(tr) {
  var tabela = document.getElementById('myTable');
  tabela.deleteRow(tr.rowIndex);
}

var botaoAdd = document.getElementById("adicionar-contato");

botaoAdd.addEventListener("click", addContato);

function addContato(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  //Criando uma tr
  var contatoTr = document.createElement("tr");

  var formContato = document.getElementById("formulario");

  //Criando 06 tds
  var nomeTd = document.createElement("td");
  var emailTd = document.createElement("td");
  var celularTd = document.createElement("td");
  var instaTd = document.createElement("td");
  var faceTd = document.createElement("td");
  var excluirTd = document.createElement("td");

  //Preenchendo as Tds
  nomeTd.textContent = formContato.nome.value;
  emailTd.textContent = formContato.email.value;
  celularTd.textContent = formContato.cel.value;
  instaTd.textContent = formContato.insta.value;
  faceTd.textContent = formContato.face.value;
  excluirTd.innerHTML = "<button class='btn btn-danger excluir'><i class='fa fa-trash-o' >Excluir</i></button>";

  contatoTr.appendChild(nomeTd);
  contatoTr.appendChild(emailTd);
  contatoTr.appendChild(celularTd);
  contatoTr.appendChild(instaTd);
  contatoTr.appendChild(faceTd);
  contatoTr.appendChild(excluirTd);

  // attach the "delete" action to this button for this row
  excluirTd.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", () => {
    deletar(contatoTr)
  })

  var agendaTabela = document.getElementById("corpoAgenda");
  agendaTabela.appendChild(contatoTr);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <form id="formulario">
    <div class="row py-2">
      <div class="col-1">
        <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-5 ">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escrava o primeiro nome" name="nome">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row py-2">
      <div class="col-1">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="email" name="email">
      </div>
      <div class="col-1">
        <label for="cel">Celular:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="(XX)XXXX-XXXX" name="cel">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row py-2">
      <div class="col-1">
        <label for="insta">Instagram:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Instagram" name="insta">
      </div>
      <div class="col-1">
        <label for="face">Facebook:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Facebook" name="face">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="salvarexcluir">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="adicionar-contato">Salvar</button>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>

<!-- Tabela que conterá os dados-->
<div class="container mt-3">
  <table class="table table-striped" id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Celular</th>
        <th>Instagram</th>
        <th>Facebook</th>
        <th>Excluir</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="corpoAgenda">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: There was still a button for removal, next to the "save" - ​​"delete" button. I would like it to be removed and the only existing button to be the table button.

Comment: But it's working much better than before. Thank you very much!!

Comment: If I'm understanding you corrrectly, that extra button was hardcoded in the HTML; I've removed it.

Comment: ok. Gracias! ;)

Comment: could you add the option to clear all fields automatically once a new contact is added?

Comment: That would really be a separate question, but all you'd need to do is set each form field's value to an empty string on that  (i.e. `formContato.email.value = ''`) after capturing the data in your new table row.