# How to send data to a table with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like someone to answer my question about how I can make the data typed in the Agenda fields be added to the table, with jQuery. Currently the table adds rows and also deletes them, but does not add the data entered in the form fields. Finally, I can't make the "save" button be placed below the table, or above it, static.

HTML - atv1-1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <title>João Augusto - Agenda jQuery</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="p-5 text-black text-center bg-roxo">
  <h1 id="titulo">João Augusto</h1>
</div>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="container">
        
        <h5>Agenda</h5>
        <form id="formulario">
            <div class="row py-2">
                <div class="col-1">
                    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5 ">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escrava o primeiro nome" name="nome">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row py-2">
                <div class="col-1">
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="email" name="email">
                </div>
                <div class="col-1">
                    <label for="cel">Celular:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="(XX)XXXX-XXXX" name="cel">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row py-2">
                <div class="col-1">
                    <label for="insta">Instagram:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Instagram" name="insta">
                </div>
                <div class="col-1">
                    <label for="face">Facebook:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Facebook" name="face">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Tabela que conterá os dados-->
    <div class="container mt-3">

        <table class="table table-striped" id="myTable">
            <tbody>
             <tr>
               <th>Nome</th>
               <th>Email</th>
               <th>Instagram</th>
               <th>Celular</th>
               <th>Facebook</th>
               <th>Excluir</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                <button type="button" onclick="remove(this)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Excluir</button>
               </td>
             </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
             <tr>

                <button class='btn btn-danger excluir' onclick="AddTableRow()" type="button">Salvar</button>
               
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
            </table>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="mt-5 p-4 bg-dark text-white text-center">
  
</div>
<script src="functions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery (JS) - *functions.js* :

```
(function($) {
  AddTableRow = function() {

    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";

    cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    cols += '<td>';
    cols += '<button type="button" onclick="remove(this)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Excluir</button>';
    cols += '</td>';

    newRow.append(cols);
    $("#myTable").append(newRow);

    return false;
  };
})(jQuery);

  
(function($) {
remove = function(item) {
  var tr = $(item).closest('tr');

  tr.fadeOut(400, function() {
    tr.remove();  
  });

  return false;
}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Your answer didn't help me much.

Comment: It is not necessary for the Select to exist.

Comment: I mean the form.

Comment: Your question has been duplicated by you !!!!! [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75177528/) = trust answered.

Comment: Not it really helps

Comment: i need my javascript to be all changed to jquery.

Comment: And I need my table to record information sent by the form that is already there. But I don't want that "Select" in my table.

Comment: just delete `<select>......</select>`

Comment: [this is answer your question, code by jQuery](https://codepen.io/ramoures/pen/bGjvPWW)

Answer (score 0):

**This is my working solution:**

[View this on codepen.io](https://codepen.io/ramoures/full/poZLBpX)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="functions.js"></script>
```

> FORM and Table, HTML: *(Just replace this instead your form and your  table*
> )

```
<form id="formulario">
        <div class="row align-items-center py-2">
            <div class="col-1">
                <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 ">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escrava o primeiro nome" name="nome" value="JOÃO AUGUSTO">
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                <label for="email">Select:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <select class="form-select" name="select">
                    <option value="">Not choosed</option>
                    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
                    <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
                    <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
                    <option value="Option4">Option4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-center py-2">
            <div class="col-1">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="email" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                <label for="cel">Celular:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="(XX)XXXX-XXXX" name="celular">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-center py-2">
            <div class="col-1">
                <label for="insta">Instagram:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Instagram" name="instagram">
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                <label for="face">Facebook:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Facebook" name="facebook">
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
    <div class="col-auto p-0 mt-3">
        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="Functions.addToTable('formulario','myTable')" type="button">Salvar</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container mt-3">
    <table class="table table-striped text-center table-bordered my-3" id="myTable">
        <tbody>

            <!-- IF EMPTY ROWS : 
            <tr id="emptyTr"><td><i>empty</i></td></tr>
            -->

            <!-- IF CONST ROWS : -->
            <tr id="tr_1">
                <td><i>name</i></td>
                <td><i>select</i></td>
                <td><i>email</i></td>
                <td><i>celular</i></td>
                <td><i>instagram</i></td>
                <td><i>facebook</i></td>
                <td>
                    <button onclick="Functions.removeFromTable('formulario','myTable',1)" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-xs">
                        Excluir
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!---end Const Rows---->

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

> **functions.js:** *(just replace all this instead your functions.js)*

```
//develope by: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3114914/
class Functions {
static trNumbers(tableId){
    var table = $('#'+tableId);
    var issetEmptyTr = table.find('tbody tr#emptyTr').length;
    if(issetEmptyTr==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return parseInt(table.find('tbody tr:last').attr('id').replace(/\D/g,''))+1;
}
static formData(formId){
    var map = new Map();
    var formInputLength = parseInt($('#'+formId+' input').length);
    var formSelectLength = parseInt($('#'+formId+' select').length);
    var formLength = formInputLength + formSelectLength;
    for(let i=0; i < formLength; i++)
    {
        var inpName = $('#'+formId+' input, #'+formId+' select').eq(i).attr('name')
        var inpVal = $('#'+formId+' input, #'+formId+' select').eq(i).val()
        var inpMap = map.set(''+inpName+'',''+inpVal+'');
    }
    return inpMap;
}
constructor(formId,tableId){

    function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    }
    var formData = Functions.formData(formId)
    var table = $('#'+tableId);
    table.prepend('<thead class="bg-light"><tr></tr></thead>')
    var th = '';
    var formDataKeys = formData.keys();
    for(let i=0; i<formData.size; i++){th+='<th>'+capitalizeFirstLetter(formDataKeys.next().value)+'</th>'}
    th += '<th>Excluir</th>';
    table.find('thead tr').html(th);
    table.find('tbody').find('#emptyTr td').attr('colspan',formData.size+1);

}
static addToTable(formId,tableId){
    var formData = Functions.formData(formId);
    var table = $('#'+tableId);
    var formDataKeys = formData.values();
    var td = '';
    var number = Functions.trNumbers(tableId);
   
    for(let i=0; i<formData.size; i++){td+='<td>'+formDataKeys.next().value+'</td>'}
    td += '<td><button onclick=Functions.removeFromTable("'+formId+'","'+tableId+'",'+number+') type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-xs">Excluir</button></td>';
    table.find('tbody').find('#emptyTr').remove()
    table.find('tbody').append('<tr id="tr_'+number+'">'+td+'</tr>')
    number++;

    //SEND and RECEIVE DATA here. for add your row data.
    //your MAP => formData. your MAP keys => formData.keys() and values => formData.values()

}
static removeFromTable(formId,tableId,rowId){

    var formData = Functions.formData(formId)
    var table = $('#'+tableId);
    var td = '<td colspan='+formData.size+1+'><i>empty</i></td>';
    $('#tr_'+rowId).remove()
    var trLength = $('tbody tr').length;
    if(trLength==0)
    {
        table.find('tbody').html('<tr id="emptyTr">'+td+'</tr>')
    }

    //for DELETE your row data, SEND and RECEIVE DATA here.
}
 
}
new Functions("formulario","myTable"); // "formulario" is your form id and "myTable" is your table id.
```

**Replace the two above and leave the rest of your code unchanged.**

It automatically puts the name of the **input/select** `name=""` in the table **header**.
And puts **input/select** `value=""` in own column.
It considers the number of your input/select correctly.
Please Look at the *`comment`* in the codes.

Your form id is *"formulario"* , your table id is *"myTable"*.
and i did'nt change it.

**For change this ids:**

go to last line of **function.js** and change:

`new Functions("your_new_form_id","your_new_table_id");`

go to your *Salvar* button and *Excluir* button `onclick=""`
and change ids:

`Functions.addToTable('your_new_form_id','your_new_table_id');`
`Functions.removeFromTable('your_new_form_id','your_new_table_id','your_table_row_number');`

**Good luck!**

my english is not good. sorry :)